# How to reverse data coming from an API in NextJs

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I have data coming from an Api and i want to reverse it, so the last one shows first but when i do reverse it in Next Js, i get this error:
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

```
//Lets say this is the API
{
post: "some content",
picture: ""
},
{
post: "some other content",
picture: ""
}
```

```
//Here is where i'm making my Api call.
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<{posts: Post[]}> = async(context) => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:7000/api/tweets`)
  const posts: Post[] = await res.json()
  
  return {
    props: {
      posts
    }
  };
};
```

```
//Here is where i reversed it.
 {tweets?.reverse()?.map((tweet: any,index:any) => (
       <div key={index} >
         <Tweet tweet={tweet} />
            </div>
   ))}
```

Or would it be better to reverse my data from MongoDb? and if it is how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try my best not to do data manipulation in my Next, but do it from within the query itself. It will save you load time, and also processing on the client side.

You can adjust your Mongodb (http://localhost:7000/api/tweets) to sort by key while querying to do the processing on the server rather than on your app.

[See Mongo docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/reference/operator/meta/orderby/)